# How do i find out localization errors such as hardcoded strings in razor views

Tags: c#, razor

My project includes numerous views and viewmodels which must use the localization resources. But some of these files contains hardcoded strings. How do i find out these strings.
In viewmodel cs files i was able to find the errors using Resharper. But Resharper couldnt find the errors in Razor views.
Could anyone please tell me how to do it